# adding 0 at the front of a bit string and 1 at the end of the bit string for N iteration

Tags: python, bit

Currently, i have a bitstring represented by

```
1 #for n = 0
```

and for n iteration, i want to add a 0 at the front and a 1 at the end of the bitstring

for n = 1:

```
011  #added 0 and 1
```

for n = 2:

```
00111  #added 0 and 1 from previous bit string
```

for n = 3:

```
0001111  #added 0 and 1 from previous bit string
```

.
.

I tried:

```
bit_str = ""
for i in range(n):
    if i == 0: 
        full_b_tree = "1"
        print(full_b_tree)
    else:
        inc_one = "1"
        bit_str += inc_one
        inc_zero = "0"
        full_b_tree += inc_zero
        print(full_b_tree)
```

but for n = 3, I'm getting

```
1
011
01110
0101110
```

It's my first time working with bitstrings as I'm not familiar with adding a 0 at the front and 1 at the end, would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: If I use `n=3` in your code, it gives me `1, 110, 11010`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was in the summation as following:

You **were** doing the following summation

```
full_b_tree += inc_zero
```

which means `full_b_tree = full_b_tree + inc_zero` which will add the `0` to the end.

You **should** do

```
full_b_tree = inc_zero + full_b_tree
```

which will append `0` to the front, which is what you want. I also replaced the `range(n)` by `range(n+1)` because `range(3)` will only go up to `2`.

```
n = 3
bit_str = ""
for i in range(n+1): # n replaced by n+1
    if i == 0: 
        full_b_tree = "1"
        print(full_b_tree)
    else:
        inc_one = "1"
        full_b_tree += inc_one
        inc_zero = "0"
        full_b_tree = inc_zero + full_b_tree # The summation corrected
        print(full_b_tree)

1
011
00111
0001111
```

Comment: +1 to the answer. One correction ```range(n)``` is alright since the iterator starts from 0 and it actually iterates for n times whereas for ```range(n+1)``` it is actually iterating n+1 times

Answer (score 1):

This should help-

```
N=3
bit_string = '1'
for i in range(N):
    bit_string = '0' + bit_string + '1'
    print(bit_string)
```

Output-

```
011
00111
0001111
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
bit_str = ""
for i in range(n+1):
    if i == 0: 
        full_b_tree = "1"
        print(full_b_tree)
    else:
        inc_one = "1"
        full_b_tree = full_b_tree+inc_one
        inc_zero = "0"
        full_b_tree = inc_zero + full_b_tree
        print(full_b_tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
def genBitStr(n):
    """ n: number of iteration"""
    for i in range(n):
        yield '1'.join(map(lambda e:e*i,['0', '1']))

for i, bit_str in enumerate(genBitStr(10)):
    print(i, bit_str)
```

`0 1
1 011
2 00111
3 0001111
4 000011111
5 00000111111
6 0000001111111
7 000000011111111
8 00000000111111111
9 0000000001111111111`